# How this complexity calculation

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I'm not familiar with this complexity calculations. Someone could tell me how

`T(n) = T(n/2) + θ(1)`  become `T(θ) = θ(log2 n)`

`log2` means  base is 2 for log

This is related to peek finding algorithm for a 1D array with `n` number of elements.

Comment: Hint: you can use Master method to show that. I guess equality is $T(n) = T(n/2) +\theta(1)$.

Comment: you are right. I changed equality to `T(n)=T(n/2)+θ(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Using Master's Method case 2 is applicable since $n^{\log_b a}=n^{\log_2 1}=1$ which is equal to $\theta(1)$. Thus from Master's method $T(n)=\theta(n^{\log_2 1}\log n) = \theta(\log n)$